# Passing data to plain HTML template file which is not associated with any component

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a generic pop up component to which I am attaching an HTML template and this template can be changed according to the situation. But for this HTML template I want to send data but this template is not in any component. It is kept in the different folder. Can I have any solution for this?

Comment: Show us what you are trying to do instead of just theoretical explanation

Comment: First of all you should post some code here, to get an answer. Second, if you use Angular, it's better that all HTML is part of a component 